# How to secure information in case of security breach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have a ASP.NET (MVC4) site which has some sensitive information, I've taken some security measures: Input validation, Using Razor syntax, all queries are performed through LINQ, forms are token-validated. Still we all know there's no system 100% breach proof.

The information is sensitive only if connected to a user, so I'd like to know if there's a way to encrypt the link, I mean, that in case of a security breach the hacker won't be able to connect users with pieces of information.

Right now I'm working with related entities in a "regular" fashion:

```
User
  -- UserId
  -- UserName

SensitiveTable
  -- Id
  -- UserId
  -- Sensitive
```

Is there a way to "encrypt" the relationship so the user is able to manage his/her information  and a potential attacker wouldn't be able to connect both tables?

Are there other security measures I should take to prevent this?

Comment: Depending on what gets compromised, the attacker will probably be able to do anything your server can.

Comment: This site runs on Azure Websites, so I don't manage the server security, in this case, do you think it's useless to implement measures in the database, but rather focus on the user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hash the user ID (or email, or something) using something like BCrypt with a system salt that is hard-coded into your application code, and maybe a per-user salt generated using your own algorithm, which will stop you doing any queries in the database that join from the User table to the Sensitive table.

That will make it difficult for somebody who gains access to your database, but not your application code, to work out the relationships.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a good measure in case the DB is compromised.